# Run Google App Script in a Protected Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets where in column A, I run a onEdit() script to insert automatically the date and time Column C was edited. That works perfectly well.

```
function addTimestamp(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var startRow = 2;
  var targetColumn = 3;
  var ws = "xxxxxx";

  if (col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){
    var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aaa");
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).getValue() == ""){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(currentDate);
    }
  }

}
```

What I need is to protect Columna A so users cannot edit the timestamps that were inserted by the script.

I tried protecting the range Column A, but the script only runs if the edit in Column C is done by a user with the permissions of the protected range.

**What I need? ** If ANY user edits Column A (no matter if it has or not the permission of the protected range) the script runs anyways.

Thanks!

I would like to receive the Script / Code

Answer (score 0):

onEdit by itself won't be able to do it, **but** you can widen its permissions by creating an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that would run on edit in your spreadsheet, running your function/s.

Go to that clock-like button at the left and set a New Trigger with these options. Save it and try to run it from another user than yourself. It should work!

[image]

PS: the timestamp would be created with your account